# A problem in integration

Tags: calculus

When reading in a mechanics book i found the d Torque= d Force * Radius 
this raised some confusion for me

why in the law in the book he considered the D torque as D force * radius not as Force * Dr 
when making an integral how to determine the delta part and the other part of integral ?

Answer (score 0):

We know that 
$$\vec{T}=\vec{r}\times \vec{F}$$
Since it's a cross product, ordering is important, thus
$$d\vec{T}=\vec{dr}\times \vec{F}+\vec{r}\times \vec{dF}$$
Both $r$'s and $F$'s change $(dr$ and $dF)$ should be taken into account unless one of them is constant. It seems that your book treats $r$ as a constant $(dr=0)$:
$$d\vec{T}=\vec{r}\times \vec{dF}$$

Comment: Or more generally, $d\vec{r}\parallel\vec{F}$.

Comment: @Jevaut why the book treated the radius as constant ? does the radius change with the force or not? THANKS